# Adding Custom action links next to 'like' and 'comment' for an Open graph publish action

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I've created Opengraph objects and actions in my app, and I'm able to post an action so that it shows up on the various channels. However, an important feature I need is that with these posts, I'd like a custom action link to appear along side the comment and like links at the bottom of the post. My assumption / understanding was that if I posted a user's action on an object in my website, the other actions that were designed to act on that object should also show. Do I have to manually connect the other actions to the object somehow?

I've tried adding the 'actions' parameter to the post data and specifying the name and link for the action but it doesn't seem to work. This does however work if I'm posting just a message to /me/feed and I can see the custom action link.

So this:

```
function publish() {
    var publish = {
    actions : [{
        name : 'Custom Action',
        link : action_url
        }]};

    FB.api('/me/appns:action&object='+object_url,'post',  publish, function(response) {

            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured:'+response.error);
              } else {
                alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
              }
    });
}
```

This works as far as publishing the action on the channels, but the Custom Action link is missing.

However, if I convert this to a plain old feed post using FB.api('me/feed', 'post', publish ....) I do see the custom action link.

Am I expecting something to work that's not in FB's current feature set?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue right now. Please post if you figure it out and I'll do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this feature is currently not supported when posting Custom Open Graph actions. We're in the process of implementing it and will be sure to announce it and add it to the documentation at developers.facebook.com/docs when it is ready. ETA is 1-2 months.